Embedded Slickgrid Table in Iframe not rendering completely(Iframe-Html)
Video -> here
'Standalone' Slickgrid Table with Frozen columns renders fine but when embedded into a html Iframe (NO SERVER),the table does not render completely.
Missing - TableHeader, Unfrozen rows do not render throughout the width of the table.
Also , tried creating the same table in BOKEH-PYTHON(which uses slickgrid under the hood) and the embedding it in a html- iframe which went  fine.However since it lacks a lot of features compared to slickgrid it can't be used.
How to embed the slickgrid table in html  to ensure its complete rendering?
Reproduction
IFRAME:
<button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('slicktable)', this,'violet')">Slicktable</button>   
    
<div id="slicktable" class="tabcontent">
             <iframe width="100%" height="100%"id = "Iframe_1" src=slicktable_path.html"></iframe></div>

EMBEDDED HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>SlickGrid Draggable Lines</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slickgrid@5.14.0/dist/styles/css/slick-alpine-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slickgrid@5.14.0/dist/browser/slick.core.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slickgrid@5.14.0/dist/browser/slick.interactions.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slickgrid@5.14.0/dist/browser/slick.grid.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .highlight-line {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 2px;
                z-index: 10;
                cursor: grab;
            }

            .highlight-line.dragging {
                opacity: 0.5;
            }

            .highlight-line.red {
                background-color: red;
            }

            .highlight-line.orange {
                background-color: orange;
            }

            .slick-row {
                position: relative;
                /* Needed for absolute positioning of lines */
            }

            .positive {
                color: green;
            }

            .negative {
                color: red;
            }

            #htmltitle {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: left;
                font-size : 20px;
            }

            #myGrid {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="htmltitle"></div>
        <script>
            const htmltitle = "\u003cdiv\u003e(2024-12-20 07:06:29)---------)\u003c/div\u003e";
            document.querySelector("#htmltitle").innerHTML = htmltitle;
        </script>
        <div id="myGrid" style="width: 1800px; height: 800px;"></div>
        <script>
            const options = {
                enableCellNavigation: true,
                enableColumnReorder: false,
                frozenColumn: 9,
            };
            //data and columns get populated  and render fine in standalone slickgrid render but not when embedded
           let data = [{},...]
          let columns = [,.....]

            const grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid",data_df,columns,options);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

